# DataTable adding additional text to a data row when a criteria is met

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a script that displays the status of device media players at locations using dataTables.
If one of the devices has no internet connection the name of the location blinks with a red background.
Is there a way I can add additional text to the location name saying "Offline". I am working with the code below which works perfectly apart from adding the additional text.

```
columns: [
  { data: 'DisplayDescription'},
  { data: 'MessageCount',"visible": false  },
],

if(data.MessageCount == 2 ) {
    $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('WayFinderStatusTableOn HeaderStatusWayfinderRedTextBlink');
    $(row).attr('title', 'Display screen offline');

    $(row).find('td:eq(0)').on('click', function () {
        $('#open_offline_help').modal('show');
    });
}

    else if(data.DisplayMainBoard == 0 && data.RecordCount >= 1){
    $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('RoomStatusTableOverrideOn') ;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Stu, Thanks for the edit, well spotted. Any idea on an answer?

Comment: Where in the DataTables configuration are you using the above code? You haven't given your full table definition, but if you  are using [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) then you could use [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to modify the cell text.

Comment: mark_b, thanks for the reply, I will take a look at columns.render

Comment: mark_b, I have added the columns.data to the question.

Comment: mark_b, I have now included the following code and it works perfectly.    columnDefs: [
            {
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return data + ' ' + ' ** Offline **';
                },
                targets: 0,
            },
            
        ], Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.